Partition(partition_name) VS Where clause
I have a table with range partitions on a date column, I used to query the data using where cause to fetch the transformed data of particular day. But as the data is huge (billions of rows) the query used to take few minutes to execute even when I i used where condition on the partition column. As I've read over internet many people claiming oracle handles the partitions internally when used where clause, but i tried to fetch the same data using partition for or partition() example.. FROM table_name PARTITON FOR(DATE '2024-09-17'), and this gave the result in few seconds.
Why so? Does oracle not handle the partition in the where clause? or is there something wrong in my table architecture?
I tried asking chat GPT it claimed that using where clause will still result in full table scan and that will take the time but it is the one who also said partitions are handled automatically when used where clause.
Edit: here is the sql used to create table:
CREATE TABLE performance_data( . . . . kpi_date DATE, . . . ) PARTITION BY RANGE (kpi_date) ( PARTITION p_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2024-05-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) );

I also scheduled a cron to create daily partitions:
ALTER TABLE performance_data SET INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY)

and yes someone created the same kpi_date column as index as well recently. But this issue of taking too long of fetch was also facing before the column was made an index.
Example query I am facing issue in:
SELECT * FROM performance_data WHERE kpi_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE-2);

The above code is way slower as compared to:
SELECT * FROM performance_data PARTITION FOR(DATE '2024-09-15');

Also i am not able to fetch the data dynamically from above query.
I am new in this field. Pls guide me what do i need to change, the query, DDL, the way I am creating partitions, how to get the dynamic data using PARTITION FOR()

Does oracle not handle the partition in the where clause? Well you'll have to show the table DDL and your WHERE clause, so we can answer that. The partition pruning works similar as index access, you must obey some simple rules to get it.

HI can you please send the explain plan for the query , the DDL of the table, if you know the data is in a specific partition then you can SELECT the dta from the partition,   SELECT [column list ] from [table name ] partition ([partition name ])

"I tried asking chat GPT" Do not rely on ChatGPT for anything in terms of factual content. It is a generative AI tool, which means it is designed solely to write content that looks right, superficially, not designed to tell you the correct answers to questions.

If you are correctly specifying a range predicate on the correct partition key column and it does not cross any partition boundary, then you should be pruning partitions with the WHERE clause. There is no advantage to using the PARTITION extended naming syntax, either legacy (by name) or newer (with the FOR clause). (The only situation where the extended naming is useful is in limiting DML locks to individual partitions to facilitate concurrent loading, or otherwise when doing heavy partition-wise ETL work. It was not intended for queries in general.)
If I had to guess, I suspect you have an index on the date column and when you use a range predicate in the WHERE clause Oracle is using this index, whereas when you specify the partition you don't have a WHERE clause and so the optimizer won't use any such index. Index use for date ranges on partitioned tables where the date column in question is also the partitioning key is generally a bad thing - you actually want a full segment scan, especially with daily partitions. Try hinting to force a full scan:
select /*+ full(mytable) */ * from mytable where datecol BETWEEN ...

If that's it I'd suggest dropping that index so it stops causing problems.

The best way to troubleshoot your problem is to investigate the execution plan showing what is Oracle doing to resolve the query.
Here a simple Set Up  of the table and some sample data to create the interval partitions
CREATE TABLE performance_data( 
id NUMBER,
kpi_date DATE,
pad VARCHAR2(1000)) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (kpi_date) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
( PARTITION p_init VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2024-05-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) );

-- add few data to ccreate partitions
insert into performance_data(id,kpi_date, pad)
select rownum id, date'2024-05-16' + rownum kpi_date, lpad('x',999,'y') pad from dual connect by level <=10;

So, lets start with the quick query that directly reference the partition:
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT * FROM performance_data PARTITION FOR(DATE '2024-05-23');

The execution plan can be obtained with the following query
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1' ));

that returns (limited for brevity)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                  |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                  |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |     9 |     9 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PERFORMANCE_DATA |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |     9 |     9 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The important part is columns Pstart and Pstop, showing basically that you scan only the 9th partition and returns data. Note that this will return immediately the first page in SQL Developer (or whatever you use)
Now lets proceed with the slow query - I use the same literal date to make it comparable.
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT * FROM performance_data WHERE kpi_date = DATE '2024-05-23';

The produced execution plan is similar with one subtle difference.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                  |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|                  |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |     9 |     9 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PERFORMANCE_DATA |     1 |   524 |   280   (3)| 00:00:01 |     9 |     9 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("KPI_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2024-05-23 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

So basically you again access only one partition, but there is a filter on the kpi_date column on the value 2024-05-23 00:00:00
The most probable explanation of your behaviour is that the kpi_date contains the time component.
Imagine you have one million row in the partition with different time component. Say ten of them (scattered through the partition) have the time component 00:00:00 you'll have to scan the whole partition to get the 10 rows and to return the first page.
So probably what you want and what is the correct equivalent of the first query is
SELECT * FROM performance_data WHERE kpi_date >= DATE '2024-05-23' and kpi_date < DATE '2024-05-24';

You me get some more information in this answer.
